# Laravel database query with case

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using laravel 5 in current project. Here is my query to database:

```
$users = User::where('status', '=', '3')->orWhere('status', '=', '2')->whereExists(function($query1)
        {
             $query1->select(DB::raw(1))
               ->from('firsts')
               ->whereRaw('firsts.user_id = users.id')
               ->where('status', '=', 'approved');
        })
        ->whereExists(function($query2)
        {
             $query2->select(DB::raw(1))
               ->from('seconds')
               ->whereRaw('seconds.user_id = users.id')
               ->where('status', '=', 'approved');
        })
        ->whereExists(function($query3)
        {
             $query3->select(DB::raw(1))
               ->from('thirds')
               ->whereRaw('thirds.user_id = users.id')
               ->where('status', '=', 'approved');
        })
        ->whereExists(function($query4) use($category_id)
        {
             $query4->select(DB::raw(1))
               ->from('jobcategories')
               ->where('provider_id', '!=', 0)
               ->where('category_id', '=',$category_id);
        })
    ->get();
```

Idea behind that is to pick all valid users. As you can see at the begining of query I wrote first condition for users. The problem is that users with `status = '2'` will never have their thirds table `status = 'approved'`. Is there possibility to put if statment before `$query3`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the query that is generated. You'll see multiple sub-select queries which is suboptimal. I'm not sure what you want to achieve with this query, but I'm guessing it could be also achieved with a few joins which should give better performance. If you elaborate a bit on what the purpose of this query is I could help with the joins.

Comment: Okey I will try to explain logic behind this query in more details. I have to pick users where status is 2 or 3 where user have records on tables: firsts seconds and thirds, where records status is approved. Problem is that users with status 2 will never have thirds table record status approved.

Comment: So why should user with status 2 be selected if they do not have a record approved and you want users with approved records? Could you add some parentheses to your query? :) Is it "where status in (2, 3) and user has approved records in all tables"? Or "Where status = 2 OR (status = 3 and user has approved records in all tables"? Or sth else?

Comment: User with status 2 must have their status approved at tables firsts and seconds, BUT user with status 3 must have their status approved at tables firsts and seconds AND thirds. At the moment i think i can use one option. Get all users with status 2 and check their status at tables firsts and seconds, write their id's into array  and after that find all users with status 3 and check their status at tables firsts, seconds AND thirds, after that -  update id's array. But I think it's wrong solution.

Comment: Do the users have only one record at maximum in firsts, seconds, and thirds or multiple?

Comment: They do have only 1 record in each table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83308/discussion-between-evaldas-butkus-and-jedrzej-kurylo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the query below

```
$users = User::whereIn('users.status', array(2, 3))
->leftJoin('firsts f', 'f.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('seconds s', 's.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('thirds t', 't.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where(function($query) {
  $query->where('users.status', 2);
  $query->where('f.status', 'approved');
  $query->where('s.status', 'approved');
})
->orWhere(function($query) {
  $query->where('users.status', 3);
  $query->where('f.status', 'approved');
  $query->where('s.status', 'approved');
  $query->where('t.status', 'approved');
});
```

I'm not sure what to do with the last part of your query, as it has no relation to any of users, firsts, seconds, thirds:

```
->whereExists(function($query4) use($category_id)
  {
     $query4->select(DB::raw(1))
       ->from('jobcategories')
       ->where('provider_id', '!=', 0)
       ->where('category_id', '=',$category_id);
  })
```

Comment: Did i understand it correctly, if user status = '2' $query query starts and if user status = '3' $builder query starts?